# find the sum to n term of $\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3} + \frac{3}{2\cdot3\cdot4} + \frac{5}{3\cdot4\cdot5} + \frac{7}{4\cdot5\cdot6 } + ... $

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

$$\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3} + \frac{3}{2\cdot3\cdot4} + \frac{5}{3\cdot4\cdot5} + \frac{7}{4\cdot5\cdot6 } + ... $$

$$=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k-1}{k\cdot(k+1)\cdot(k+2)}$$ $$= \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot k + \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{3}{k+1} - \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{5}{2\cdot(k+2)} $$

I do not know how to get a telescoping series from here to cancel terms.

Comment: You can use $$\frac{2k-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{2k}{k(k+1)(k+2)}-\frac1{k(k+1)(k+2)}.$$

Comment: You do mean an *infinite* sum, not a *finite* sum, right?

Comment: @ConnorHarris I think this means writing the partial sums explicitly.

Comment: @ConnorHarris, a sum that can be expressed in n.

Comment: Note that the $\frac{3}{k+1}$ term for some value of $k$ cancels the $\frac{-1}{2k}$ and $\frac{-5}{2(k+2)}$ terms for adjacent values of $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2k-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}&=\color{blue}{\frac{3}{k+1}}-\frac{5/2}{k+2}-\frac{1/2}{k}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac12}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{k+1}}-\frac1k\right)+\color{blue}{\frac52}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{k+1}}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: There's a typo after the first $=$ sign, it should be $\frac{5/2}{k+2}$. Can't edit though, since edits must be 6 characters at minimum.

Comment: @a_guest Thank you.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let the fractions be $\frac{a}{k}$, $\frac{b}{k+1}$, and $\frac{c}{k+2}$.

$\frac{a}{k}+\frac{b}{k+1}+\frac{c}{k+2}=\frac{a(k+1)(k+2)+bk(k+2)+ck(k+1)}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{2k-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$

We want the following

$a+b+c=0$

$3a+2b+c=2$

$2a=-1$

Solve, $a=-\frac{1}{2}$, $b=3$, and $c=-\frac{5}{2}$.

The rest is standard.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You can merge the parts of the series for which the denominator is similar and you will see they cancel each other. Then you are left with the terms for which the denominator is either smaller than $3$ or greater than $n$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{-1}{2k} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3}{k+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{k+2} \\
& = \left[-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{-1}{k}\right] + \left[\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{6}{k+1}\right] - \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5}{k+2}\right] \\
& = \frac{3}{4} + \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{-1}{k}\right] + \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^{n+1}\frac{6}{k}\right] - \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^{n+2}\frac{5}{k}\right] \\
& = \frac{3}{4} + \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{-1}{k}\right] + \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{6}{k} + \frac{6}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}\right] - \left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{5}{k} + \frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{n+2}\right] \\
& = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=3}^{n}\left[\frac{-1 + 6 - 5}{k}\right] + \frac{6}{2}\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{n+2} \\
& = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)} - \frac{5}{2(n+2)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When terms are in A.P in denominator, we use difference 
of last and first terms in product to distribute the terms 
of denominator over numerator, to change into 
telescoping series.