# Finding the sum formula of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Hello I'm trying to derive the sum formula of the following series

> $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{2n+1}{n\cdot \left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)}$

I'm not sure what to do anymore I've tried to apply partial fractions and got

> $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:\:}\:\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{3}{2\cdot \left(n+2\right)}\right)$

Is it possible to apply the telescoping test on this series?

I'm trying to find $S_n$

Comment: Very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972505/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3093887/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972505/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998674/42969

Answer (score 5):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\frac{An+B}{n(n+1)}-\frac{A(n+1)+B}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{An+2B}{n(n+1)(n+2)},$$and therefore$$\frac{2n+1/2}{n(n+1)}-\frac{2(n+1)+1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}.$$So, the sum of your series is$$\frac{2+1/2}{1\times2}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+1/2}{n(n+1)}=\frac54.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$S_p=\sum _{n=1}^{p \:\:}\:\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{3}{2 \left(n+2\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}H_p+\left(H_{p+1}-1\right)-\frac 32\left(H_{p+2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{2}{p}+\frac{7}{2 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

since

$$\frac1{2n}+\frac1{n+1}-\frac{3}{2(n+2)}=\int_0^1\frac{1+2x-3x^2}{2x}x^n dx$$

we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2n}+\frac1{n+1}-\frac{3}{2(n+2)}\right)=\int_0^1\frac{1+2x-3x^2}{2x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{1+2x-3x^2}{2x}*\frac{x}{1-x}dx=\frac12\int_0^1 (3x+1)dx=\frac54$$